# Java & MySQL- Rankings

Tags: java, mysql

I am making a game and I require a ranking system. I already save all the stats like kills, deaths, wins, innocent shots, etc with MySQL. I am clueless a the moment on how I would be able to rank everyone. I want to have it over MySQL but they will be updated very quickly. I was thinking I could load all ranks in a HashMap when the game starts but that would be very ineffective since there are thousands of players. I want to also use most of the stats to work this out. Could someone explain to me how I would be able to do this? Thanks!

Comment: When the user queries for rank, why don't you calculate the rank in real-time and display it back to the user?

Comment: There are going to be a lot of games being played at the same time so I'd need to use MySQL so no one gets the same rank.

Comment: Why not use a *TimeStamp* to state that "the ranks at <TimeStamp> are as: <Ranks>." This will eliminate the problem of having same user have different ranks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use mysql Events to trigger a stored procedure. The stored procedure would execute the ranking and store the rank in the db. You would then just set the event trigger time to whatever you wanted, say 10 minutes.

mysql events: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events.html

```
CREATE
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
    EVENT
    [IF NOT EXISTS]
    event_name
    ON SCHEDULE schedule
    [ON COMPLETION [NOT] PRESERVE]
    [ENABLE | DISABLE | DISABLE ON SLAVE]
    [COMMENT 'comment']
    DO event_body;
schedule:
    AT timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...
  | EVERY interval
    [STARTS timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...]
    [ENDS timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...]

interval:
    quantity {YEAR | QUARTER | MONTH | DAY | HOUR | MINUTE |
              WEEK | SECOND | YEAR_MONTH | DAY_HOUR | DAY_MINUTE |
                DAY_SECOND | HOUR_MINUTE | HOUR_SECOND | MINUTE_SECOND}
```

Then you would setup a stored procedure to generate the rank and set it for your players:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-views.html

An example procedure would be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT)
    BEGIN
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t;
    END
```

You can make the procedures as complex as you need to.